# Two classes annotate each other in a single file

Tags: python, annotations, circular-reference

```
class BotData:
    """Class holding data of one specific bot"""

    common: dict
    users: Dict[Union[int, str], dict]
    __bots_data: BotsData
#                ~~~~~~~~

@dataclass
class BotsData:
    """Data of needed entities, None for no data or not used"""

    telegram: Optional[BotData]
    viber: Optional[BotData]
    vk: Optional[BotData]
    whatsapp: Optional[BotData]
    inter: Optional[dict]
```

It fails with a `NameError`.

Both classes have type annotations for the properties of each other's type (`BotsData` and `BotData`). How can I change my code so it runs? What negatives does `from __future__ import annotations` bring?

Comment: "This code runs fine" - This is incorrect. This code normally fails because BotsData is not defined at the time of evaluation. Please include your imports - because the only way it will work is with from future import and it changes *a lot*

Comment: Thanks, was blinded by the fact that functions are evaluated only at runtime. Could you explain what 'include your imports' means, considering the fact that the code above is in a single file? Also __future__ annotations is quite interesting, but after a brief search I can't imagine what do you mean by 'a lot', are there some major downsides?

Comment: Well, "a lot" here means working vs not working at all... I see you edited your description to match that it doesn't work at all, so it's fine now. | Anyways: you need to either use `from __future__ import annotations` or quote the BotsData in first class (i.e. `__bots_data: "BotsData"`). Normally annotations are evaluated as they appear and `BotsData` is not yet defined. Before the PEP existed to postpone the evaluation (that import right now, in the future it's supposed to become the default), using string literal with class name was the only way to do that.

Comment: @h4z3 Appreciate your explanation! Decided to use the future feature, as this project relies on new version already. You might post an answer so the other visitors will have an easier time facing the same problem